# How to tell which external libraries are not 64 bit supported in the Android Studio project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, 64-bit

I have just received an email from Google Play store saying our app is not 64 bit supported:

"As the deadline approaches, we wanted to remind you that at least one of your apps* uses native code but does not currently offer a 64-bit variant"

What I dont understand is that we dont use native code in the project, I suspect one or more External Libraries in the project are using native code, my question is how do I identify them and how to make them 64 bit supported?